# How to dynamic loadind dojo's 1.8 modules with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, dojo, dgrid

I have in my main page dojox/layout/ContentPane widget. This widget dynamically load any Hrefs    with content which have Javascript & HTML the being formed by PHP.
Javascript

```
        $scriptCode .= 'require(["' . $scriptFile . '", "dojo/ready"], function(PageScript, ready){' . "\n";
        $scriptCode .= '    ready(function(){' . "\n";
        $scriptCode .= '        setTimeout(function(){new PageScript(' . $scriptOptions . '); }, 0);' . "\n";
        $scriptCode .= '    });' . "\n";
        $scriptCode .= '});' . "\n";
```

PageScript() is a dojo class drawing widgets and logic of page. The problem consists in that that when loading other href the object of old page partially gains properties of new objects. Removal of object of page after an drawing , destruction of widgets don't help to solve a problem.

PageScript

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'common/widget/Card'], function (declare, pageWidget) {
return declare(pageWidget, {
    constructor: function(options){
    }
});
});
```

PS. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Um, your code and question don't make a lot of sense. If you want to load dynamically created content into a ContentPane the easiest way is to pass in a dojo template. Just use `data-dojo-type` to create any widgets that you need. If you need to run code on widget load, put it in the widget's `startup` function.